# Stop mosquitto autorestart on centos7

Tags: service, centos, mosquitto

I'm trying to stop the Mosquitto broker service on a centos 7 server.

I've stopped the service with

```
sudo systemctl stop mosquitto.service
```

then I've disabled it with

```
sudo systemctl disable mosquitto.service
```

with ps I still get

```
/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

if I kill it, it autorestarts automatically and even after a reboot It's still running.

The process is owned by an other user (admin).
How can I stop it definitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with mosquitto but how systemd manages its services.

`systemctl disable` only affects the autostart of the service but a disabled service will still get started if another service depends on it.

Lets say you have got a service `mqtt-client` depending on `mosquitto` with e.g. `Wants=mosquitto`. Every time `mqtt-client` is started the `mosquitto` service gets started as well, even if it is disabled.

So one way is either to prevent `mqtt-client` from starting as well (and all other services which depend on `mosquitto`) or remove the dependency.

Another approach is to totally prevent the service from being loaded by masking it:
`systemctl mask mosquitto` - this way you can neither start it manually nor by another service.

I would recommend reworking your dependencies in the long run since masking will just create a symlink to `dev/null` so nothing happens if service gets loaded and you are not able to start it by yourself without unmasking it first.